# How to get email notifications when someone likes my Facebook post?

Tags: facebook

I get email notifications when someone comments on my Facebook post but not when someone likes it. I went through the notifications settings and couldn't find where to set the like notification on/off. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

It's there in the notifications section, it's just far down and buried amongst a lot of others.

From **Account Settings** or **Privacy Settings**, choose **Notifications** in the sidebar menu. Expand the **Email** section and *Turn On* any notifications you wish to receive.

**Likes on your post** is about half-way down the list.

[image: email notifications for likes]

Comment: Your list has a lot more options plus you have 3 radio buttons and I have two. I am assuming only options which are turned off will show in the list. I don't see "Likes on your posts" so it's probably turned on but I don't get any emails for those.[link](http://tinypic.com/r/2ypjlar/5)

Comment: @Tony_Henrich [Stack-Imgur link to the image in your comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uIHAx.gif).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they eliminated this option.

The advice given by phantom42 is incompatible with the settings I see today as of 11-28-2014 using Chrome.